# Klipfolio (Podio integration) is missing values

Tags: json, datasource, podio, klipfolio

Using API I have exported data from my Podio app into Klipfolio but somehow not all data is being exported. When trying to show all values from a field, only some of them are shown.

I have tried to find the root of the problem by contacting Klipfolios support but have gotten the following answer

"The data in the datasource is all of the data being returned by the service you are connected to via the API, if there is a discrepancy in what you are seeing in the service portal and the datasource then you will need to contact that service to determine the issue as it is not something that Klipfolio is restricting "

As an example of the problem I have included two screenshots.

- A screenshot of the Podio app export called "Personale"

[image: Podio screenshot].

> In column R (highlighted in red) the values for the "Stilling" field is seen. There is a total of 155 values.

- A screenshot from Klipfolio with the values from the "Stilling" field put into a table:
  [image: Klipfolio screenshot].

> As seen there is only 80 items and when I scroll down some of them is not even from the "Stilling" field, but from the one of the other fields.

Somehow not all values are being exported into the Klipfolio data source (JSON format). Can anyone tell me how I can solve the problem, or do I need to provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, since I haven't actually played around with Podio as such, but I've once heard that there is some kind of limitation on how much data you can pull out at once from Podio. Try to check that out :)

Comment: Hi Adam. I tried deleting some of the data but I am still having the same problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Your Klipfolio config says: `@/items/fields[16]/values/...`, which expects to have needed data **always** at 16th position.

Luckily Podio doesn't return value if there is no value to return, so you can't use this straight-forward approach. So, field that you expect to be 16th will be 15th if 15th is empty. And you have to address fields differently (e.g. by name, or id) which will be constant and won't depend of other fields and won't depend on app fields re-arrangements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Pavlo mentioned, you will need to filter based on a JSON record name and not the indices of the JSON record as not all field arrays will be in the same position for each item. The following JSON expressions should return all the value records for where the label of the field is "Stilling"

```
@/items/fields[label='Stilling']/values/value/text
```